# Help Understanding Aegir

Tags: multi-sites, aegir

So I've been struggling with installing Aegir for about a week now, and trying to understand how it should work, and hopefully get it resolved. (BTW, here is a related issue if you're curious:  http://drupal.org/node/1202568 )

First, lay of the land:

- RedHat 5.5
- MySQL 5.5.13
- Apache 2.x
- PHP: 5.3.2

I am installing using this command

```
drush hostmaster-install --aegir_host=hostname --aegir_db_user=myadmin --aegir_db_pass=adminpasswd --aegir_root=/pathto/aegir
```

So my guesses of what needs to happen to get Aegir up and running:

- Upon a successful install, there should be a sites/hostname directory where Aegir lives
- This directory should contain a settings.php files
- This settings.php file grabs the database credentials that are set in a file inside the vhost.d directory using SetEvn, right? The vhost.d directory is empty. But an entry is needed to get Aegir up and running, right?

Does this make sense? What am I missing?

KM

Comment: Specific to your question, are you running that drush command as the Aegir user?
(assuming you created an aegir user or something similiar) Did you run through the tutorial: http://community.aegirproject.org/installing ? Is this a fresh install, or are you trying to install Aegir onto a current drupal instance? I personally had issues installing it on Ubuntu. I ended up spinning up a new EC2 instance using Debian 6, and ran through their install tutorial without issue. Cheers.

Comment: To answer your questions: Yes, I am running drush as the aegir user; following the manual steps to install; this is a fresh install.

Comment: Were you able to successfully install the latest provision release?     

`drush dl --destination=/var/aegir/.drush provision-6.x`

Comment: Thanks @ChrisV: Yes, that portion installed w/o issue. It is step 10.3 of the manual install process is where we are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(2nd Attempt!)
It almost looks like the symbolic link they have you create in step [3.1.1](http://community.aegirproject.org/node/389#Apache_configuration), is not working correctly and may be causing this issue.

I don't know anything about the differences between Debian and RH 5.5, but maybe RE doesn't have a /etc/apache2/conf.d directory, in which case you would have to manually add an include line into httpd.conf

Cheers.

Comment: Many thanks @ChrisV. Have been able to make quiet a bit of progress. Now, going to http://hostname.com shows what is in /var/www/html -- standard apache welcome page, but not what is in /var/aegir ... Any ideas how that might work ... ? RHEL's apache's confs are in /etc/httpd/conf and the binaries are in /usr/sbin/. The paths shouldn't matter, right? As long as they can be read by apache?

Comment: @KM01 If that is a folder, you need to make sure there is a symlink
`ln -s /var/aegir/config/apache.conf /etc/httpd/conf/aegir.conf`
just make sure that the apache.conf file exists.